# Itext7 not showing arabic text

Tags: c#, pdf, arabic, itext7, non-ascii-characters

I am trying to create a Pdf document using IText7. Despite the table looks as expected, just found a big problem, this does not show Arabic letters.

I've tried adding new fonts and changing the encoding.
I'm displaying Arabic letters in the wrong direction and they are separated, changing the base direction from right to left didn't help.

This is the part of the code:

```cs
string font = "naskh.ttf";
PdfFontFactory.Register(font);
FontProgram fontProgram = FontProgramFactory.CreateFont(font, true); 
PdfFont f = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(font,true);
Cell cell = new Cell(1, 3)
    .Add(new Paragraph(" English عربي "))
    .SetFont(f).SetFontScript(UnicodeScript.ARABIC)
    .SetFontSize(33).SetBaseDirection(BaseDirection.RIGHT_TO_LEFT)
    .SetFontColor(DeviceGray.WHITE)
    .SetBackgroundColor(new DeviceRgb(80, 140, 80))
    .SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
```

The result is like this:
[image: Result]

I've tried everything I could find online, lots of them are java or older version, I tried to change them to work on c# Itext7 but still no result
the closest I cot was with `PdfFont f = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(alaw, "Identity-H", true);`
where I got 3 letters in the wrong order

I even tried to use `\u0644\u0648\u0631\u0627\u0646\u0633 \u0627\u0644\u0639\u0631\u0628` (copied from an answer as string, but still not shown.

I can't use paid add-ons
Any solution to be able to write Arabic?

Comment: you do require a paid add-on ([pdfCalligraph](https://itextpdf.com/en/products/itext-7/pdfcalligraph)) to render Arabic with iText7.

Comment: so there is no other way? i am trying to create a word document now maybe this can work

Answer (score 1):

add language Processor:

```
        LanguageProcessor languageProcessor = new ArabicLigaturizer();
```

and modify cell or PdfDocument like that:

```
  com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument tempPdfDoc = new com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument(new PdfReader(pdfFile.getPath()), TempWriter);
        com.itextpdf.layout.Document TempDoc = new com.itextpdf.layout.Document(tempPdfDoc);
        com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph paragraph0 = new com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph(languageProcessor.process("الاستماره الالكترونية--الاستماره الالكترونية--الاستماره الالكترونية--الاستماره الالكترونية"))
                .setFont(f).setBaseDirection(BaseDirection.RIGHT_TO_LEFT)
                .setFontSize(15);
```

the final will be something like :

```
    String font = "your Arabic font";
    PdfFontFactory.register(font);
    FontProgram fontProgram = FontProgramFactory.createFont(font, true);
    PdfFont f = PdfFontFactory.createFont(fontProgram, PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H);
    LanguageProcessor languageProcessor = new ArabicLigaturizer();
    com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument tempPdfDoc = new 
    com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument(new PdfReader(pdfFile.getPath()), TempWriter);
    com.itextpdf.layout.Document TempDoc = new 
    com.itextpdf.layout.Document(tempPdfDoc);
    com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph paragraph0 = new 
    com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph(languageProcessor.process("الاستماره الالكترونية--الاستماره الالكترونية--الاستماره الالكترونية--الاستماره الالكترونية"))
                .setFont(f).setBaseDirection(BaseDirection.RIGHT_TO_LEFT)
                .setFontSize(15);
```

//and look how i useded setBaseDirection & and don't use TextAlignment ,it will work without it

Answer (score 0):

For C# this worked for me (The font type so important I used arial arabic)

```
using iText.Layout;
using iText.Layout.Element;
using iText.Layout.Properties;
using iText.Kernel.Geom;
using iText.IO.Font;
using iText.Kernel.Font;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf; // used iTextSharp for ArabicLigaturizer class and you have to use it unless you gonna get reversed words
using PdfWriter = iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter;
using PdfDocument = iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument;
using PdfEncodings = iText.IO.Font.PdfEncodings;
using PdfFont = iText.Kernel.Font.PdfFont;

string arabicFontPath = @"Full path to your font\alfont_com_arial-1.ttf";
FontProgram fontProgram = FontProgramFactory.CreateFont(arabicFontPath, true);
PdfFont f = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(fontProgram, PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H);
var arabicLanguageProcessor = new ArabicLigaturizer();

table.AddCell(new Paragraph(arabicLanguageProcessor.Process(item.NameAr ?? DefaultValue))
    .SetFont(f)
    .SetBaseDirection(BaseDirection.RIGHT_TO_LEFT)
    .SetFontSize(14));
```