# c# , how to generate password protected arabic pdf or word document

Tags: c#, pdf

I used Itext7 in my C# code to create a pdf file, as I said in my other question here

[Itext7 not showing arabic text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68169423/itext7-not-showing-arabic-text)

so I gave up on trying to fix it, because it seems like I need to pay for the addon, and I can't do that

I tried Pdf sharp, it showed arabic letters but there were disconnected and reversed, and writing arabic backward did not make the letters connect

I used SautinSoft library and it created a word document where arabic works fine, but it has a footer that says that it is a free version, so i can't use this one either
the pdf created by this library also doesnt support arabic

so I think I can't write pdf in arabic, all libraries I tried didn't supported it

is there anyway to fix it?
or can anyone please suggest another library that can create arabic pdf or a word document without watermarks or footers

Comment: You appear to ask for a library recommendation. That's off topic on stack overflow. You might want to look at [softwarerecs.se] instead.

Comment: You can check [Free Spire.PDF](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FreeSpire.PDF/) library, it supports drawing Arabic text in pdf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, using Gembox pdf, it only allows 20 paragraphs, but that is more than enough

Answer (score 0):

What if DocumentCore?

```
 public static void SecureDocument()
    {
        string filePath = @"ProtectedDocument.pdf";

        DocumentCore dc = new DocumentCore();

        // Let's create a simple document.
        dc.Content.End.Insert("Hello World!!!", new CharacterFormat() { FontName = "Verdana", Size = 65.5f, FontColor = Color.Orange });

        PdfSaveOptions so = new PdfSaveOptions();
        // Password Protection
        so.EncryptionDetails.UserPassword = "12345";
        // EncryptionAlgorithm
        so.EncryptionDetails.EncryptionAlgorithm = PdfEncryptionAlgorithm.RC4_128;
        //Permissions: Content Copying, Commenting, Printing, Changing the Document, filing of form fildes
        //Printing: Allowed
        so.EncryptionDetails.Permissions = PdfPermissions.Printing;

        // Save a document as the PDF file with Security Options.
        dc.Save(filePath, so);

        // Open the result for demonstration purposes.
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(filePath) { UseShellExecute = true });
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).